# How can I change the default behavior of redirects in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have this in my route file:

```
 devise_scope :user do
   get "/admin", :to => "users/sessions#new"
 end
```

I can access the sing in form by going to `http://localhost:3000/admin`. When I click on `Sign in` without providing `username` and `password` it redirects me to the `/users/sign_in` path with error message about missing username and password.

I think it is default behavior of Devise. But on sing in error, I want be redirected to the `/admin` instead of default `/users/sign_id`. How can I achieve this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  devise_for :users
  as :user do
    get 'admin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'admin' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
  end
```